# parameter expansion with substitution in bash

Tags: bash

I have a trivial problem with regular expression in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
FNAME=$1
echo ${FNAME//.*\/tests\//}
```

I want to remove everything before /test/ including the /test/ as well. Because of some reasons ".*" doesn't work.

```
$ ./eclipse/unittest.sh /foo/tests/bar
/foo/tests/bar
```

How do I select anything in bash reg exp?

Comment: _Parameter expansion_ are **not** REGEX

Comment: The correct usage of the substitution operator would be `${FNAME//*\/tests\/}`, but the accepted answer is cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#` followed by a pattern to remove everything up to and including the pattern.  It will use the shortest match:

```
function f {
    echo ${1#*/tests/}
}

$ f /foo/tests/bar
bar
$ f /foo/tests/bar/tests/last
bar/tests/last
```

If you want to use the longest match, you can use `##`:

```
function f {
    echo ${1##*/tests/}
}

$ f /foo/tests/bar
bar
$ f /foo/tests/bar/tests/last
last
```